# linux while read to switch columns if column 3 is less than column 2

Tags: awk, csv, read

I have a tab separated files with entries like this:

1 4 10 cat

1 10 4 dog

I want to process it so that if column 3 is less than column 2 they get switched, like so

1 4 10 cat

1 4 10 dog

This script seems to get it, but it only outputs columns that don't meet the criteria, so the output would be just

1 4 10 cat

```
while read field1 field2 field3 field4; do
  if [[ "$field2" -gt "$field3" ]] ; then 
      awk '{t=$field2; $field2=$field3; $field3=t; print; } '
  fi
done < filename.txt
```

I'm sure I'm making some stupid mistake, but at the moment I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '$3 < $2 { temp=$3; $3=$2; $2=temp } { print }' /path/to/file
```